# Reactive akka stream : How to delay the graph shutdown until the source has dried out?

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, akka-stream, alpakka

I am trying to feed data (say 10 strings) to an akka-stream graph from a kafka broker

Here's the graph in an unittest :

```
val consumer = AlpakkaConsumer(KafkaBootstrapServer(kafkaURL).value, "porteur-id")

val drainingControl =
  Consumer
    .plainSource(consumer.kafkaConsumerSettings, Subscriptions.topics("transaction"))
    .toMat(Sink.seq)(Keep.both)
    .mapMaterializedValue(DrainingControl.apply)
    .run()

val streamComplete = drainingControl.drainAndShutdown()
Await.result(streamComplete, Duration.Inf).size should be > 0
```

The unittest fails (size equal to 0, 10 expected)

However, If I insert a `Thread.sleep(5000)` before my drainAndShutdown() call, It passes.

It gives me the impression that, whithout the sleep, the graph is directly closed after the run() call, and it has not the time to even process the first message. If I introduce a sleep command, it can go through all the source content, it closes the graph and I have something in the end.

I don't see what I am doing wrong, since it is basically a snippet that you can find everywhere, and used as an example

How can I trigger the drainAndShutDown call only when the source has delivered all the messages ?

Thanks for your help !!

Note : I am using a akka-stream-kafka 0.22 version

Answer (score 0):

According to Alpakka [Kafka's docs](https://doc.akka.io/api/alpakka-kafka/current/akka/kafka/scaladsl/Consumer$$DrainingControl.html), `drainAndShutdown` behavior is:

> Stop producing messages from the Source, wait for stream completion and shut down the consumer Source so that all consumed messages reach the end of the stream.

That means that you'll stop receiving messages in your consumer, and it will process only what's already been enqueued.

For testing streams, I'd recommend taking a look at [Streams TestKit](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-testkit.html#streams-testkit), as it gives you lots of control over which parts of your streams you want to test

Comment: It's also of questionable utility, to my mind to unit test the Kafka consumer (which is already well-tested).  With Akka Streams, it's not difficult to put the logic of what you're doing with the messages from Kafka into its own stream and test that with mock data.